# Decrypt in PHP with Salt, password, and type?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes

When I run Crypto-JS's encrypt function, I am given the base64-encoded following:

```
var crypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase",  {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC}).toString();
==>  "U2FsdGVkX19HKyOimD43Bl4ww/I40M+NQrscjti3ZnA="
```

How do I unencrypt this in PHP in the future?  I have attempted using openSSL, mcrypt, etc, and nothin seems to work -- I guess I don't know how to deal with base64 encoding, salting, VI, and everything... Something goes wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JS**

```
    // encrypt data with CryptoJS

    var crypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

    // get additional info from CryptoJS ecnrypted data

    var data_base64 = crypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    var iv_base64   = crypted.iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    var key_base64  = crypted.key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

**PHP**

```
    $encrypted = base64_decode("data_base64"); // data_base64 from JS
    $iv        = base64_decode("iv_base64");   // iv_base64 from JS
    $key       = base64_decode("key_base64");  // key_base64 from JS

    /* MCRYPT */
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv );

    // remove padding added by crypt algorithms
    $plaintext = rtrim($plaintext, "\t\0 "); // remove tab-, zero- and space-padding

    /***************************************/
    /* OPENSSL */
    $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
    // or
    $plaintext = openssl_decrypt("data_base64", 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); // works with base64 encoded data from JS
```

Comment: Is it insecure storing the iv in a database or something?  My users are aware of their key, but not of the IV.  What is the best way of dealing with the IV?

Comment: I have spend two days to solve this problem but find your answer and it almost work but have error when use $encrypted = base64_decode("data_base64");  openssl_decrypt add error that can't decode base64 and I have remove $encrypted = base64_decode("data_base64") just live $encrypted = "data_base64" and work perfect